# generic method, getting ambiguous invocation error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, generics, type-constraints

I'm using the Repository Pattern and was trying to build a generic method, as i have a few object which pull from their repositories in the same way:

My Repositories are created in this manner:

```
public interface IEntityRepository<T> : IDisposable

public interface IAuditorRepository : IEntityRepository<Auditor>

public class AuditorRepository : IAuditorRepository
```

The Auditor class if defined as:

```
public class BaseEntity : IObjectWithState

public partial class Auditor : BaseEntity
```

Aside from AuditorRepository, I have a few others such as BuildingRepository.  Now I'm trying to create a generic method, in which I could pass the Repository:

```
    public List<EditSelectItemViewModel> GetItems<T>(IEntityRepository<T> repos) where T : BaseEntity 
    {
        var d = repos.All.Where(x => x.isActive).OrderBy(x => x.Name).Include(z => z.Contracts)
            .Select(y => new EditSelectItemViewModel
            {
                Id = y.Id,
                SourceName = y.Name,
                DisplayOnNew = y.DisplayOnNew,
                NumberOfTimesUsed = y.ActiveContracts.Count(a => a.isActive)
            }).ToList();

        return d;
    }
```

But I keep getting an error on the .Where stating that this is an ambiguous reference.  All Repositories implement the All method, for example below is the AuditorRepository version:

> ```
>     public IQueryable<DomainClasses.Auditor> All
>     {
>         get { return _context.Auditors; }
>     }
> ```

The IEntityRepostiory is defined as:

```
    public interface IEntityRepository<T> : IDisposable
{
    IQueryable<T> All { get; }
    //List<T> AllRequests { get; }
    IQueryable<T> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties);
    T Find(params object[] keyValues);
    void InsertOrUpdateGraph(T entityGraph);
    void InsertOrUpdate(T entity);
    void Delete(params object[] keyValues);

}
```

and the baseEntity is:

```
    public class BaseEntity : IObjectWithState
{
    public State State { get; set; }
}
```

State is defined as:

```
    public interface IObjectWithState
{
    State State { get; set; }
}
public enum State
{
    Added,
    Unchanged,
    Modified,
    Deleted
}
```

Comment: Is the `All` property defined in the interface `IEntityRepository<>` as well?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yes, i just updated my question to include it.

Comment: Could you post the implementation of the class `BaseEntity` ?

Comment: @ZenLulz done, added to my question above.

Comment: Yes, and please give the exact error message you receive.

Comment: Then what would `.isActive` in the first lambda `x => x.isActive` be?

Comment: Error Message is T' does not contain a definition for 'isActive' and no extension method 'isActive' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: isActive is a property in the Auditor class.

Comment: I believe I get it now, BaseEntity needs to have .isActive not the derived classes, since I told the method T was of type BaseEntity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I initially thought, the Ambiguous invocation error occurs because the lambda expression `x => x.isActive` is not valid, due to a lack of definition of the variable `isActive` in the class `BaseEntity` (class used as constraint of the type parameter in the method `GetItems`).

The error can be reproduced using this code:

```
(new object[0]).AsQueryable().Where(o => o == notDefined);
```

In my context, `notDefined` is not defined, raising at the same time the Ambiguous invocation error on the Where extension method. As soon as the lambda expression is fixed (e.g. `o != null`), the error is no longer thrown.

A screenshot of this Ambiguous invocation error with the other methods that match.

[image]